# Export email to EML format which contains EML attachments

Tags: export, outlook-redemption, eml, rfc822

We are using Redemption from an Outlook addin for save messages to EML format (RFC822).

There was an unfortunate situation when one of out customer attached several EML file attachments into her email (and these emails were saved with Redemption).

The generated EML is not the same if I open in Outlook like the original message.

IMHO the issue caused by the fact the attached EML files using the same "00B0FEED_message_boundary" ID for message part boundaries.

I try to explain below:

```
... headers ..

Content-type: Multipart/mixed; charset=iso-8859-1;
 boundary="00B0FEED_message_boundary"
Content-Description: Multipart message


--00B0FEED_message_boundary
Content-type: Multipart/alternative; charset=ISO-8859-1;
 boundary="00B0FEEE_message_boundary"
Content-Description: Multipart message


--00B0FEEE_message_boundary
Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Description: Message text

... message body in plain text format ...

--00B0FEEE_message_boundary
Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Description: HTML text

... message body in HTML format ...

--00B0FEEE_message_boundary--
--00B0FEED_message_boundary
Content-type: application/octet-stream; charset=iso-8859-1;
 name="=?iso-8859-1?Q?1=20Ab-=20und=20Zuschl=E4ge=2EEML?="
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename="=?iso-8859-1?Q?1=20Ab-=20und=20Zuschl=E4ge=2EEML?="
Content-Description: =?iso-8859-1?Q?1=20Ab-=20und=20Zuschl=E4ge=2EEML?=

... first attached message headers ...

Content-type: Multipart/mixed; charset=3Dutf-8;
 boundary=3D"00B0FEED_message_boundary"                           <------ inner message boundary ID
Content-Description: Multipart message


--00B0FEED_message_boundary
Content-type: Multipart/related; charset=3DISO-8859-1;
 boundary=3D"00B0FEEE_message_boundary"
Content-Description: Multipart message


--00B0FEEE_message_boundary
Content-type: Multipart/alternative; charset=3DISO-8859-1;
 boundary=3D"00B0FEEF_message_boundary"
Content-Description: Multipart message


--00B0FEEF_message_boundary
Content-type: text/plain; charset=3Dutf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Description: Message text

... first attached message body in plain text ...

--00B0FEEF_message_boundary
Content-type: text/html; charset=3Dutf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline
Content-Description: HTML text

... first attached message body in HTML ...

--00B0FEEF_message_boundary--
--00B0FEED_message_boundary--

--00B0FEED_message_boundary

... several other similar EML messages
```

This message not opening correctly in Outlook, but if I change the inner message boundary ID (and modify the corresponding part in the inner message) the EML opening correctly. So I presume this similar ID the cause of my issue.

Is there any workaround to force to use random ID for message boundary? Maybe to force to BASE64 encode the attachments?

Comment: What version of Redemption are you using?

Comment: We are using the 5.20 release

Comment: Have you tried the latest version (5.22)? Can you save the problematic message in Outlook as an MSG file, zip it (important!) and send it to  redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com?

Comment: I've tried using the 5.22 version, and it solved the issue. Thank you.